# How can I configure Postfix to ignore relayhost for some domains?

Tags: postfix, smtp

Is there a way in Postfix to ignore the `relayhost`?

I have something like

```
relayhost = [smtp.domain.net]:587
```

Now for a certain domain I don't want to send it out to that relay but want it to just send from that machine.

How do I have to configure Postfix to do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> *main.cf*
>   #relayhost = [smtp.domain.net]:587
>   transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
>
> */etc/postfix/transport*
>   domaintodeliverdirectyto :
>   * smtp:[smtp.domain.net]:587

Don't forget to `postmap /etc/postfix/transport`

May want to use `relay` instead of `smtp` as the transport mechanisim.
For reference http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html

Comment: For those wondering about the difference between transport mechanisms I found this helpful: https://mailing.postfix.users.narkive.com/5ZaGRrTO/postfix-transport-relay-vs-smtp-for-gateway