# Postfix: Ignore relay host when from specific address

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, smtp

I configured my postfix server to relay all received mails to smtp.example.com with `relayhost`. This server doesn't accept mails from an external source. So only scripts are sending mails.

Is it possible to configure postfix that all mails with a specific mail address in **FROM** field, like script@domain.net (or also the whole domain: domain.net) are send directly by the server to the corresponding mx server for the TO-address, instead of using the specified relay host?

I found one possibility to specify a specific host if a specific mail address is in the TO field, but not the **FROM field**: [How can I configure Postfix to ignore relayhost for some domains?](https://serverfault.com/questions/320992/how-can-i-configure-postfix-to-ignore-relayhost-for-some-domains) and http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html

Thanks!!

Comment: or also the other way around is possible where all mails with @example.com in from field are relayed to a specific host, all others sent directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't look closely enough.

You'll want [`sender_dependent_relayhost_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_dependent_relayhost_maps) or one of the things that override it.